# Implementing product() in XSLT

Tags: xslt

XPath 2.0 (and 3.0) has convenient aggregate functions sum() and avg(), but nothing that returns the product of a sequence of numeric atomic values.

Although implementing such a function is trivial in a language that allows assignment statements, it seems not to be that easy in XSLT. The only way I've found to get an aggregate product is to use recursion:

```
<xsl:function name="fn:products">
  <xsl:param name="input" />
  <xsl:param name="total" />
  <xsl:if test="exists($input)">
    <xsl:variable name="x" select="$input[1] * $total"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="$x"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="fn:products(subsequence($input,2),$x)"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:function>
```

But the above is actually my adaptation of a function that appears on p.994 of Michael Kay's book XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 4th Edition. The original function outputs a sequence of running balances by recursively adding a sequence of numbers.

My version just multiplies the numbers, instead of adding them. The result is then a sequence of "running products". For example, fn:products((4, 0.75, 10, 0.7), 1) returns the sequence 4, 3, 30, 21.

Since I'm only interested in the product of all numbers, I just take the last item of the output with a filter expression: fn:products((4, 0.75, 10, 0.7), 1)[last()].

It works. But just for the sake of making good code, I wonder if there is a way to make the function to just directly return the last item as the aggregate product (i.e. just get 21, in the example above).

I tried a couple of things, but they just broke the function. Is there a way to achieve this? Is it possible also to implement it in a better, leaner way (the original function was not meant to return a singleton sequence)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use one of the fancy processors, you can use dyn:evaluate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
    <num>4</num>
    <num>0.75</num>
    <num>10</num>
    <num>0.7</num>
</test>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dyn/dyn.xml"
  extension-element-prefixes="dyn"
>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="run">
            <xsl:for-each select="test/num"><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:if test="position() != last()"> * </xsl:if></xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:value-of select="dyn:evaluate(string($run))"/>

    </xsl:template >
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Evaluating an XPath expression constructed at runtime as a string. Yeah. This is a very good solution. It hadn't occurred to me. Works well with altova:evaluate() and should also work well with saxon:evaluate(). Thank you, faster.